# Translated text in PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I get a problem with some tests, when message contains specials caracters.
My app is multilanguage, So I send text via

```
trans('msg.user_created')
```

here is the code of notification:

```
noty({
        layout: 'bottomLeft',
        theme: 'kz',
        type: 'success',
        width: 200,
        dismissQueue: true,
        timeout: 3000,
        text: "El usuario <br/> se cre&oacute;",
        template: '<div class="noty_message"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4 noty_icon"><i class="icon-trophy2 "> </script>
```

and here is the PHPUnit message:

```
Failed asserting that the page contains the HTML [El usuario <br/> se creó]. Please check the content above.
```

Any Idea how to fix it???

Comment: Have you verified response content that Phpunit is getting?

Comment: You should verify what exact content you are getting when running phpunit. Maybe for example you are getting it translated into another language

Comment: response content that Phpunit is getting in on the post : Failed asserting that the page contains the HTML [El usuario <br/> se creó]. Please check the content above.

Comment: do you have the mbstring extension enabled?

Comment: Wait.. your asserting if it equals `El usuario <br/> se creó`, but the string being received by phpunit is `El usuario <br/> se cre&oacute;` ?